# How to change clock and calendar language in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, language-support, calendar, clock

After a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install, the clock and the calendar are showing in a language I can not identify:

[image]

[image]

In the Language Support dialogue only English is to be found:

[image]

And regional settings are tweaked to European English:

[image]

How can I change the clock language to English (or something else I understand) ?

Comment: Log out and log in again.

Answer (score 2):

I followed this prompts above, after opening language support I was prompted to install language updates and going to region formats and chose English United States and rebooted. Then my calender changed to English.

[image]